# не работает таймер в React. Использую useEffect и useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Прошу помочь. Код вроде простой, но я что-то явно не понимаю :)
В моём понимании: Компонент монтируется, и запускается timer. Каждую секунду он уменьшает seconds на 1, а значение seconds в свою очередь отображается на странице.

В реальности, отображается число 59 и всё. Дальше не идёт.

```js
const LoaderTimer = (props) => {

  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(60)

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(seconds - 1)
      if (seconds < 0) {
        clearInterval(timer)
        props.closeTimer()
      }
    }, 1000)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='LoaderTimer LoaderTimer_active'>

      <p className="LoaderTimer__timer">{seconds}</p>

      <div className='LoaderTimer__holder'>
        <div className="LoaderTimer__preloader">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В реальности, отображается число 59 и всё

Причина  почему так происходит это у каллбэк функции который вы передали к `setInterval` есть доступ к переменной `seconds` только в первом render-е.У него нет доступа к переменной `seconds` во втором render-е потому что `useEffect` не вызывается второй раз.

Переменная `seconds` имеет значение 60 всегда внутри `setInterval`

В таком случае для решения этой проблемы у вас есть два пути.

**Первый**: Передать массиву зависимостей переменную `seconds` чтобы `useEffect` вызывался после каждого обновления  `seconds`

```
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(60)

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (seconds > 0) {
        setSeconds(seconds - 1);
      }
    }, 1000)

    return () => clearInterval(timer)
  }, [seconds]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
       <p className="LoaderTimer__timer">{seconds}</p>
    </div>
  );
```

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-worker-yhzpd?file=/src/App.js:108-455)

**Второй**: Использовать  [**функциональное обновления**](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). Таким образом коллбек всегда будет получать актуальный стейт БЕЗ использования массива зависимостей `useEffect`.

```
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(60);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (seconds > 0) {
        setSeconds((sec) => sec - 1);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p className="LoaderTimer__timer">{seconds}</p>
    </div>
  );
```

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-ritchie-9ysip?file=/src/App.js)

Минус второго варианта в том что дойдя до значения нуля наш таймер не остановится. Почему так происходит? Потому что `useEffect` не обновляется. Соответственно это линия кода `if (seconds > 0) {` не работает.

Для того чтобы решить эту проблему, нужно использовать `useRef`

```
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(60);
  const intervalRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds((sec) => sec - 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }, []);

  const cancelInterval = () => {
    if (seconds < 1) {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    }
  };

  cancelInterval();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p className="LoaderTimer__timer">{seconds}</p>
    </div>
  );
```

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-violet-btj8e?file=/src/index.js)

Таким образом мы в каждом render-е проверяем если значение меньше один то останавливаем таймер иначе он продолжает  работать.

Также о работе `setInterval` в React можно прочитать [**тут**](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)