# Как сделать, чтобы на Реакте useEffect срабатывал раз в N секунд?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как сделать,чтобы на Реакте useEffect срабатывал например раз в 5 секунд. Я так понял, надо зависимость написать?

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237308/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2-react-%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8E-useeffect-%D0%B8-usestate

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать `useEffect` который запускается 1 раз и запускает `setInterval`. В `setInterval` мы можем запускать необходимую функцию с заданным интервалом милисекунд. Получается примерно так:

```js
// import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("id:", id);
      setState((prevState) => prevState + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>State:{state}</div>;
};

// export default App;


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, [count]);
  return <div className="App">{count}</div>;
}
```