# clearInterval не работает

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

Некорректно работает clearInterval(). Когда я навожу на элемент, значение width не должно увеличиваться, но этого не происходит. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./Notification.module.scss";

const Notification = (props) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const [intervalID, setIntervalID] = useState(null);

  const handleStartTimer = () => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setWidth((prev) => {
        if (prev < 100) {
          return prev + 0.5;
        }

        clearInterval(id);
        return prev;
      });
    }, 20);

    setIntervalID(id);
  };

  const handlePauseTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleStartTimer();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      onMouseEnter={handlePauseTimer}
      onMouseLeave={handleStartTimer}
      className={styles.notificationItem}>
      <p>{props.message}</p>
      <div style={{ width: `${width}%` }} className={styles.bar} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Notification;
```

Comment: Поставьте логи какие-нибудь, выведите console.log('set interval id', intervalID'), console.log('clear itnerval:',intervalID) в нужных местах. Вероятно где-то либо не очищается интервал, либо создается лишний. Либо обработчик какой-нибудь не отрабатывает.

Comment: @vanesicks изначально я использовал код этого человека [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYKmqeU6lOI&t=1429s). У него всё работает идеально, уже голова взрывается.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237308/%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2-react-%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8e-useeffect-%d0%b8-usestate/1237336#1237336