# React: useEffect setInterval

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, useeffect

имею довольно так стандартный useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
       //fetch API
    },2000)
},[])
```

для определенного компонента обновляю данные с интервалом, понимаю, что, нужно уходить в другую сторону чтобы избавляться от подобного,
возник как вопрос, как лучше сделать, чтобы интервал запускался только когда перешли на страницу с данным компонентом и соответственно останавливать когда ушли с нее, была идея отслеживать по url, возможно можно как то иначе?

Comment: У вас и так интервал запускается когда вы переходите на страницу. А останавливать будете в `return` на том же самым `useEffect`-e. Подробный ответ про таймеров тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237308/%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2-react-%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8e-useeffect-%d0%b8-usestate/1237336#1237336

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, а если я сделаю первую загрузку fetch и в then буду запускать интервал для обновления, как мне тогда в таком случае обнулить интервал?

Comment: К переменной присваиваете значение и потом чистите интервал также как на ссылке которой я предоставил, не понимаю в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Жизненный цикл компонента

```
// вызывается после рендеринга компонента.
componentDidMount() {
  this.timer()
}

// Сам таймер
timer(){
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => //fetch API,
      2000
    );
}

// вызывается перед удалением компонента из DOM
componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);//удаляем таймер 
}
```

Comment: а это точно ответ?